# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3 (An error occured while executing doInBackground())

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm getting an array out of index error when running the following code.

```
public class GetImageFileTask extends AsyncTask {

    private OnGetImageFileListener listener;

    public GetImageFileTask(OnGetImageFileListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        File imageFile = null;
        ImageHelper imageHelper = (ImageHelper) params[0];
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) params[1];

        try {
            imageFile = imageHelper.getFileFromImageView(imageView);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return imageFile;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object imageFile) {
        listener.onGotImageFile((File) imageFile);
    }
}
```

I do not understand why. This code works in another project but not in the one I am currently working on. Here is the error log.

```
02-13 17:20:21.073  30900-30985/app.protoype3 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
Process: app.protoype3, PID: 30900
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
        at app.protoype3.GetImageFileTask.doInBackground(GetImageFileTask.java:24)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Please show the code from where you are calling the `AsyncTask`

Comment: `AsyncTask` has 3 type parameters, whereas you are using the raw type. Also you've overridden a varargs method `doInBackground(Params... params)` with a method accepting an `Object[]`. That's a recipe for huge confusion (although I don't think it has anything to do with your actual problem).

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

Maybe error is that your params have length of 1? How do you execute your AsyncTask?

You need to call `task.execute(imageHelper, imageView)`.

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot. I forgot to add the imageView part to my task.execute call.